# Why in wordpress htaccess http to https redirection works only for homepage?

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have a wordpress site. I need to redirect all http requests to https. There are a lot of instructions online, but what I've done in .htaccess file works only for homepage (mydomain.com/) and not for other requests.

I show you my .htaccess.
Thanks in advance!

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
RewriteRule ^min/\w+\.(css|js) - [E=cache-control:no-vary]

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
### marker MINIFY start ###
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/min/(\w+)\.(css|js)$
RewriteCond %1/wp-content/cache/$2/$1.$2 -f
RewriteRule min/(\w+)\.(css|js) wp-content/cache/$2/$1.$2 [L]
</IfModule>
### marker MINIFY end ###

## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# redirect to HTTPS
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# BEGIN LiteSpeed
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN LiteSpeed` and `END LiteSpeed` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule Litespeed>
SetEnv noabort 1
</IfModule>
# END LiteSpeed
```

Comment: You need to perform this external redirect _before_ WordPress’ own rewriting starts to take control.

Comment: are you telling me that Wordpress with code or database link is forcing something different than my instructions?

Comment: I am saying that WP’s own rewriting probably interferes here. You should always do such external redirects first (place them further up in the file), than any internal ones that are intended to make the page routing work.